# Creating a words tree with Dictionary class

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to create a Tree of words with the class Dictionary in as3.

I will show a schema of what i desire:

```
      a                       b              ......
     / \                     / \
  an     ad ....           be   bi ......
 / \    / \               / \   / \
```

ant and ...
  / \  / \
 ... .. .....

and so on.....

So, i want to check (given a particular word) exists in my particular dictionary.

I have an array with my set of words (let's say 10.000), how should i fill the dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use `Dictionary` to create a tree structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like maybe you're confusing the `Dictionary` with the book kind of dictionary. In AS3, a `Dictionary` is like an `Array` except it uses a object (key) to look up another object (value). You could use this but you'd probably have to nest hundreds of them together to get the result you want.

I think for this particular case you would want to look at using some type of Tree data structure. Unfortunately, there is no native `Tree` class in AS3 but you could find more information about them online ([WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)) and I know you can get a solid implementation of a tree in [this DS library by Polygonal](http://polygonal.github.com/ds/).